# Image build stuck - Step 14/25 : RUN & 'c:/solr/bin/solr.cmd

Tags: docker, container

Have been trying to setup the sitecore docker with command below:

```
Import-Module Sitecore.DockerImages.Management -Force -Verbose

# Check parameters:
#-VersionsFilter ".*\\9\.0\.1 rev\. 171219\\.*sitecore-xpsingle.*\\windowsservercore-ltsc2016$" `

Invoke-SitecoreDockerImageBuild `
  -BuildRootPath "c:\\docker\\Sitecore\\docker-images\\sitecore" `
  -VersionsFilter "9.0.2 rev\. 180604*" `
  -AssetsSourcePath "c:\\Software\\Sitecore\\Repository\\" `
  -AssetsTransformPath "c:\tmp" `
  -Registry "VSWebsiteRegistry.azurecr.io" `
  -Isolation 'None' `
  -PushMode 'Never'
```

I keep getting the error below:

```
Step 14/25 : RUN & 'c:/solr/bin/solr.cmd' start -p 8983;     Expand-Archive -Path (Join-Path $env:INSTALL_TEMP '*.zip') -DestinationPath $env:INSTALL_TE
MP;     Expand-Archive -Path (Join-Path $env:INSTALL_TEMP '*Configuration files*.zip') -DestinationPath $env:INSTALL_TEMP;     Install-SitecoreConfigura
tion -Path $env:SIF_CONFIG     -SolrUrl "http://localhost:8983/solr"     -SolrRoot "c:/solr"     -SolrService "void"     -CorePrefix $env:SOLR_PREFIX   
  -Skip "StopSolr", "StartSolr";     Get-Process -Name "java" | Stop-Process -Force;
 ---> Running in 239c7b045448
Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8983
Started Solr server on port 8983. Happy searching!
[91mExpand-Archive : The path '' either does not exist or is not a valid file 
[0m[91msystem path.
At line:1 char:116
+ ... rt -p 8983; Expand-Archive -Path (Join-Path $env:INSTALL_TEMP '*.zip' ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:String) [Expand-Archive], IOE 
[0m[91m   xception
[0m[91m    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Expand-Archive
[0m[91m
```

I'm not able to figure out what I've done wrong here.

Looks like SOLR is started but the script is stuck on this step 14/25.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you've changed the `VersionsFilter` to `VersionsFilter "9.0.2 rev\. 180604*"`.
Inside that folder in https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images/sitecore, it has build files for different configurations, XMScaled and XPSingle.

The default VersionsFilter (in the README) has `-VersionsFilter ".*\\9\.0\.1 rev\. 171219\\.*sitecore-xpsingle.*\\windowsservercore-ltsc2016$"`
You can see in that filter that it specifically looks at folders with `sitecore-xpsingle` (i.e only the XPSingle configuration.

Therefore, you're trying to build more configurations than you probably need to.

The fix is to change it back to the original VersionsFilter I mentioned above, or, as you've said, to add the packages so that the XMScaled configuration can also be built.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces this issue, make sure all these packages exists on your local repository drive:

Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (WDP XM1 packages).zip

Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (WDP XP0 packages).zip

Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (WDP XPScaled packages).zip